# SQL Server Varchar to Datetime conversion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a varchar representing a datetime in this form :

```
dd-MM-yyyy HH:MI:SS AM
```

How can I convert it to datetime type ?

I have checked the list of standards of datetime [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms187928.aspx) But I see no corresponding one to my  format above.

Comment: Which format You want ???

Comment: It's stated in the question :) dd-MM-yyyy HH:MI:SS AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it directly

```
select CAST('10-02-2014 05:10:22 AM ' AS DATETIME)
```

Try this too..

```
 select CONVERT(varchar(15),GETDATE(),105)+' '+CONVERT(varchar(30),CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108))+' '+SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(30),CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),100)),18,2)
```

Comment: Thank you Krish :) Between how does Sql Server figure out for exemple that 10 is representing the days and 02 the month ?